# Sobolev space on the circle (Fourier series)

Tags: fourier-series, sobolev-spaces

Query: In what reference could I find the definition of the Sobolev space using Fourier series? I mean the following:

The Sobolev space with the Fourier transform is defined by

$$H^2(\mathbb{R})=\left\{u\in L^2(\mathbb{R}: \int_{\mathbb{R}} (1+\xi^2)^2|\widehat{u}(\xi)|^2\,d\xi<\infty\right\}$$
where $\widehat{u}$ is the Fourier transform of $u$.

So the Sobolev space with fourier series should be the following?

$$H^2(\mathbb{T})=\left\{u\in L^2(\mathbb{T}): \sum_{m\in\mathbb{Z}}(1+m^2)^2|\widehat{u}(m)|^2<\infty\right\}$$
where $\widehat{u}$ is the Fourier series of $u$.

thank you

Comment: By reference, do you mean like this note? https://www.math.ucdavis.edu/~hunter/m218a_09/Lp_and_Sobolev_notes.pdf. On page 46 I think the author gives a similar definition.

Comment: Oh, thank you. Yes!